# Caesar's cipher with a list of integers

Tags: haskell, recursion

I still new in Haskell and I'm trying to write a function such that The input parameter for the cipher is a list of integers, instead of just one integer. The first character is ciphered using the first integer as the parameter, the second character with the second integer, etc. If you run out of integers, you start using them from the start.

this is what I got so far:

```
import Data.Char

--encode is for encoding one character with one interger
encode :: Int -> String -> String  
encode shift msg = 
    let ords = map ord msg  
        shifted = map (+ shift) ords  
    in  map chr shifted

-- this is the troubling part, I try to use head to send the first element of string and the first element of intgers' list
cipher :: [Int] -> String -> String
cipher x str =
    let splitedstr= (head str)
        splitedint= (head x) -- parse error on input splitedint
    in encode splitedint splitedstr ++ cipher x str
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't encode then work on a `Char` instead of a `String`?

Comment: I voted to close since there is no question and no error is presented.

Comment: The capitalised "The" in the middle of your first sentence looks suspiciously like the beginning of an assignment copied and pasted verbatim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem statement, I think the `encode` function itself should operate on `Char` and not on `String`. You can thus adapt this to:

```
encode :: Int -> Char -> Char
encode shift = chr . (+ shift) . ord
```

Next you can simply use `zipWith` and `cycle` to construct the string:

```
cipher :: [Int] -> String -> String
cipher shifts = zipWith encode $ cycle shifts
```

When implementing these, I get:

```
*Main> cipher [1,2,4] "HelloWorld"
"Igpmq[ptpe"
```

in `ghci`.

In case you want to write the recursion yourself, you could do this as follows:

```
cipher :: [Int] -> String -> String
cipher shifts = cipher2 shifts shifts
```

and

```
cipher2 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> String -> String
cipher2 _ _      []     = []
cipher2 s []     ts     = cipher2 s s ts
cipher2 s (x:xs) (t:ts) = (encode x t):cipher2 s xs ts
```

You thus pass `cipher` to `cipher2` and `cipher2` has a first argument which is the entire sequence of shifts (such that it can restart when running out of shifts). Furthermore in case the string has reached its end, we return an empty list (string). Otherwise we simply call `encode` on the heads of both the string and the shift-list and call `cipther2` recursively on the tails.

Finally there is a semantical issue: it is possible that for instance you provide `z` to the `encode` function. If you shift it, it will thus run out of the alphanumerical range which may not what you want. In that case you should probably use modulo.

Comment: Thansk @willem. you are a brilliant. I missed the fact that I could use char from the begining.

Comment: There is sth that I don't understand though. encode and cipher should take two parameter but in the code you worte only one parameter!! @Willem

Comment: That is because if `f x y = g x y` can be rewritten in haskell as `f x = g x`. You thus add the parameter both to the left and right implicitly so to speak.

Comment: @YassineBoutabia: it is called [*eta-reduction / eta-conversion*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).

Comment: Thank you for your time and the clarification